# Document Library Folders in Folder Hierarachy not match when load in Asp TreeView Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Document Library which contains Folders and Files, Successfully show items with proper relation but folder in folder Hierarchy not match properly
http://oi62.tinypic.com/nyembb.jpg

Currently Items maintain in Document Library as in Picture A, but my code generate as in Picture B

```
using (var site = new SPSite(projectInitiationRequest.ProjectUrl))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        SPDocumentLibrary myDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[Constants.ProjectLibrary];

        for (int i = 0; i < myDocLib.Folders.Count; i++)
        {
            TreeNode treeHeadNode = new TreeNode();
            treeHeadNode.Text = myDocLib.Folders[i].Name;
            treeHeadNode.Value = myDocLib.Folders[i].ID.ToString();
            treeHeadNode.ShowCheckBox = false;
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeHeadNode);

            for (int j = 0; j < myDocLib.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                if (myDocLib.Items[j].File.ParentFolder.Name == myDocLib.Folders[i].Name)
                {
                    TreeNode treeChildNode = new TreeNode();
                    treeChildNode.Text = myDocLib.Items[j].Name;
                    treeChildNode.Value = myDocLib.Items[j].ID.ToString();
                    treeChildNode.NavigateUrl = myDocLib.Items[j].Url;
                    treeHeadNode.ChildNodes.Add(treeChildNode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To traverse a tree structure such as a folder and all sub folders and files, you need a recursive function. It cannot be done with loops (except if you use a stack)

Comment: See http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively (look for the c# example)

Answer (score 0):

@Tarik Thanks for the hint (Recursive calling) found the solution which Loads folders, files hierarchy in Tree View

```
TreeNode node = new TreeNode();
SPDocumentLibrary myDocLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists[Constants.ProjectLibrary];
SPFolder root = myDocLib.RootFolder;
string baseURL = web.Url.ToString();
Utilities.GetFolderNode(node, root, baseURL);
node.Text = myDocLib.Title;
node.NavigateUrl = myDocLib.DefaultViewUrl;
treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
```

Ref: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37530/Document-Library-Tree-View-Web-Part-for-SharePoint